# How do I configure apache to redirect requests in a reverse proxy when "File does not exist:"?

Tags: apache-2.2, httpd

I've created a proxy in apache that overlays styles from a test site over content from a production site. This works fine, however there are a number of files that exist in prod.site.com/static (that are content managed) but not in test.site.com/static. This shows with a number of "File does not exist:" errors in the apache log.

From HTTPd:

```
<VirtualHost *:82>
    ProxyPreserveHost Off

    ProxyPass /static/ http://test.site.com/static/
    ProxyPass / http://prod.site.com/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://prod.site.com/

    ServerName hybrid.site.com
</VirtualHost>
```

Can anyone offer advice on the best way to fall back to prod.site.com/static if a file can't be found in test.site.com/static? I'm looking into using mod_proxy_balancer but it seems like a dead end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mod_rewrite sounds like an answer for your problem. For practical examples, see [the official guide](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/rewrite_guide_advanced.html#redirect404)

Comment: Still tweaking a bit... but it's looking promising!